# Prevent android to kill app on background while waiting for intent result

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Is possible to prevent android from stop/kill an app when it goes background.

I have an app which uses native camera and sometimes when it is called, the app killed because of  not enougth memory.

Then, when I took a picture and go back to the app this is restarted. Can this be solved in any way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is possible to prevent android from stop/kill an app when it goes background.

Not really.

> Can this be solved in any way.

Fix your bugs, whatever they are. After all, there are *many* ways that your app will go into the background (HOME, user tapping on a `Notification`, user accepting an incoming phone call, user choosing another app from the recent-tasks list, etc.). If your app is going to be useful, you have to handle this scenario.